# Overleaf not showing all references from Mendeley

Tags: biblatex, citing, overleaf, mendeley

I am using Mendeley to store my references and Overleaf to write my document. When I link both together I get a .bib file in Overleaf which is missing references despite having refreshed/synced both softwares.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Please clarify what's going on. If I understood your posting, you (a) seem to be using Mendeley to create the bib file and (b) are using Overleaf to write and compile a LaTeX document and (c) have discovered that not entries you thought were stored in the bib file actually were stored. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: JKainth I see you've already contacted us and we're looking into this on our side. I've left a general answer below for the benefit of future searchers. :-)

Answer (score 2):

(I'm on support staff at Overleaf.)

The first step to try is to unlink and re-link your Mendeley account in your [Overleaf account settings](https://www.overleaf.com/user/settings). Sometimes the connection between Overleaf and Mendeley can be interrupted, and re-linking your accounts can restart the syncing process.

[image]

If that doesn't work, please write to us at support@overleaf.com. The problem may be specific to your account and we can take a closer look and suggest the proper steps to solve the problem.